# Connection to Server successfully but got some crap after json format strings

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I have successfully connected to a server, and getting correct json format String from it. Somehow 9 out of 10 times it return with something extra.. like some crap code i don't recognize. sometimes its just incomplete data. I wonder what I did wrong or what I didn't do..

does anyone has the same problem? and how can I fix it?

```
NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tempSiteString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:siteURL
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", sqlString];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[sqlString length]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                           returningResponse: &response
                                                       error: &error];

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
```

here is the code i change the received string to json

```
NSDictionary *tempNSDictionary = [resultString JSONValue];
if(tempNSDictionary.count==0)
{
    return nil;
}
//NSLog(@"Check Point after dictionary");
NSArray *tempNSArray;
if(tempNSDictionary)
{
    //NSLog(@"Check Point getArrayFromJsonString 1");
    tempNSArray = [tempNSDictionary objectForKey:@"object_name"];
    //NSLog(@"Check Point getArrayFromJsonString 2");
}

return tempNSArray;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the incorrect JSON data by accessing this JSON API outside your iOS app? Maybe its a server side issue.

Comment: @supermantoby, the information you have provided is incomplete. Please provide sample data (with crap) that you received from server. So that anyone can help you

Comment: @stuar no, on android it didn't happen...

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti the crap doesn't happen that often... i just found out its not incomplete data... its repeating part of the json file after the end of json format...

Comment: @supermantoby, Implement NSURL Connection delegate methods and wait for until data loads. If crap repeats some times only, may it is a server side issue.

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti after a while of researching, i tried to implement NSURLConnectionDelegate like you said.. just can't find a complete example or source code to figure out how it works....